# How to stop the ping command if there is no reply after 1 sec?

Tags: ping

I'm writing a loop that checks whether a connection has been established.

I'm doing

```
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
while [ $? -ne 0 ] do
  sleep 0.5
  ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
done
```

Now I'm not sure how this works, if the ping request got blocked on its way out (iptables or other) the command and the script will hang indefinitely. What I want is to stop waiting for a reply after 1 sec and send a new request. That until I get a reply faster than 1sec, the `$?` is equal to 0 and it breaks the loop.

Comment: I guess you meant `$?` instead of `$0`?

Comment: does your ping have a `-W` option? Other OS's will have a `-w` for a timeout setting.

Comment: @JeffSchaller whichever contains the exit code, I think it's `$?`

Comment: Also consider http://serverfault.com/questions/200468/how-can-i-set-a-short-timeout-with-the-ping-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ! (ping -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null); do
  sleep 1
done
echo "< 1 sec reply received...exiting"
```

Comment: that is a clean code, so basically in bash when you brace a command in parenthesis it outputs the exit code ?